# How to stop Nginx redirecting to default server?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm setting up Nginx with PHP 5.3 for multiple websites running wordpress for example. I just added a new site and it's being redirected to the default welcome page. I can't see any 'real' errors in the logs.

Here's my abbreviated nginx.conf :

```
http {
    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;
    index index.php index.html;

    server {
        listen          80 default_server;
        server_name     _;
        root            /opt/nginx/html;

        location / {
        }
    }

    server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com *.example.com;                      
        rewrite ^       $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        root /home/example/example.com;

        location / {
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/example.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Comment: OK, it seems there wasn't anything wrong with the nginx.conf file. It was PHP5-FPM failing because it was missing a directory configured for it's log file!

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by comments, the listen directive in the server block define it as the default (source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

```
listen       80  default_server;
```

The following declaration is meant as an invalid server name (source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) (so it never intersect any of your valid domain) :

```
Server_name _;
```

To fix you problem, make sure you have a server block with listen (port) and server_name (virtual host) - this one will be triggered first as you go from 'more precise to less precise' when you do virtual host names matching in nginx:

```
Listen 80;
Server_name your-domain-name.com;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cloudweavers, I'd like to keep the default as a fallback say if the IP address is accessed instead of a domain name - is that possible?

Comment: This is incorrect.  The `default_server` listen flag is what marks a server as default.  `server_name _` has no special meaning.

Comment: I just tried commenting out the default server block and nothing changed - i still got the default welcome page for my domain instead of it's index.php page

Comment: Wow, not enough coffee here! I've updated the answer with some more accurate information...

Comment: Thanks for the update @CloudWeavers this doesn't seem to solve my problem as I already had a server_name with the specific domain (www.example.com in my example) which isn't catching it as far as I can tell.

Comment: You reload NGINX after each modifications ? and www.example.com isn't the same as example.com, you have the good one?